# Undefined Scope in Angujar JS Form issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I'm having trouble binding form data (which is complete) to my controller. Below is my code:

```
<form name="form_foto" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>URL de la foto: </label>
            <!--
            <input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="http://ejemplo.com/foto.jpg">
            -->
            <input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="http://ejemplo.com/foto.jpg" data-ng-model="mifoto.foto" name="foto">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Lugar: </label>
            <input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="Lugar de ejemplo" data-ng-model="mifoto.lugar" name="lugar">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Año: </label>        
            <input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="2016" data-ng-model="mifoto.anio" name="anio">
        </div>
        <!--
        <button class="btn btn-default">Guardar Foto</button>
        -->
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-ng-disabled="datosNoValidos()" data-ng-click="guardarFoto()">Guardar Foto</button>
    </form>
```

guardarFoto Function code:

```
$scope.guardarFoto = function(){        

        alert($scope.mifoto);   //comes out undefined   

        $scope.misFotos.push($scope.mifoto);
        delete $scope.mifoto;     

    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why is that **data-ng-model="mifoto.foto"** instead of **ng-model="mifoto.foto"**?

Comment: @Anson That's because of HTML5 supporting!

Comment: Make sense. Thanks. @MeTe-30

Comment: You need to declare that  `$scope.mifoto` is an object.
You can somethink like  `$scope.mifoto = {}` at the top of your controller.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet or jsfiddle link to this error?

Comment: @Adr tried adding that object declaration to the top of my controller. Still didn't work. Thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just initialize `$scope.mifoto = {}`.
Check this live example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.misFotos = [];
      $scope.mifoto = {};

      $scope.guardarFoto = function() {

        alert($scope.mifoto); //comes out undefined   

        $scope.misFotos.push($scope.mifoto);
        delete $scope.mifoto;

      }
    }
  ])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="form_foto" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>URL de la foto:</label>
      <!--
            <input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="http://ejemplo.com/foto.jpg">
            -->
      <input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="http://ejemplo.com/foto.jpg" data-ng-model="mifoto.foto" name="foto">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Lugar:</label>
      <input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="Lugar de ejemplo" data-ng-model="mifoto.lugar" name="lugar">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Año:</label>
      <input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="2016" data-ng-model="mifoto.anio" name="anio">
    </div>
    <!--
        <button class="btn btn-default">Guardar Foto</button>
        -->
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-ng-disabled="datosNoValidos()" data-ng-click="guardarFoto()">Guardar Foto</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried your code snippet, but the alert prints [Object object], as a result of the $scope.mifoto = {} initialization, I suppose

Comment: @JuanM Alert() cannot show you object content dude!. try console.log()

Comment: I was just trying to view an example value of whatever does reach the controller. To that efect, one can do alert($scope.mifoto.lugar), for instance. console.log is obviously corect as well. Marking this as the correct answer. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: One more thing to point out: The HTML i pasted in my question is actually, angular-included HTML (data-ng-include). A thing that should also be taken into acount when binding the included html form data is that it has to be prefixed with $parent. For example: 
    {{my.model}}
    <my-component ng-model="$parent.my.model"></my-component>
This was found on --> https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1924

Answer (score 0):

Initialize mifoto outside ur function.

```
$scope.mifoto = {};
```